# Optimal way to build a Brawler Barbarian character that fights with his fists?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation

What is the best way of building a brawler barbarian that fights with his fists only? I am thinking of using the Suli class along with incremental elemental assault so I dont blow it all in one go.

Comment: Visiting a Pathfinder forum may suit your needs a little better. (http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?233032-PF-Anger-Management-A-Pathfinder-Guide-to-the-Barbarian)

Comment: Hello and Welcome. Unfortunately, here on SE, we want questions that have "correct" or "best" answers (Check out the [Tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour)). As it stands, your question is far too broad for this site, and as Ruut suggested, a forum might be better suited for your problem. Alternatively, try to narrow the focus of your question down a bit, like "Is Suli with Incremental Elemental Assault a viable choice for a Brawler Barbarian?".

Comment: See http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/are-character-optimization-questions-on-topic to see how you might rescope a char-op question to be on topic.

Comment: Consider going monk instead. They are hard to play, but a personal favorite for some of the fun things you can do with them.

Comment: @theresawalrus im opting for brawler for the barbarian gesalt.

Comment: Probably invest a loot in grapple then, though I don't know a lot about those mechanics. Consider asking "how to make a brawler Barbarian who uses unarmed combat and grappling as his attacks" instead, though that is still to broad. perhaps "[Race/Feat/Skill/Point buy/what you need help with specifically] recommendations for a brawler Barbarian who focuses on unarmed combat and grappling"